# How to get the event value as json when using Google Cloud Firestore Triggers?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using [Google Cloud Firestore Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#event_structure) to trigger a cloud function when a document has been created in Firestore. It works fine but I cannot find how to get the payload as json. Pretty much all I do is:

```
/* Triggered when a comment is created, updated or deleted.
* Trigger resource is: 
* 'projects/myproj/databases/(default)/documents/books/{bookId}'
*/
exports.bookAdded = async (event, context) => {
    let data = event.value;
    console.log(data);
}
```

Printing `data` above it looks like this:

```
{
    createTime: '2023-02-22T07:17:31.413935Z',
    fields: {
        title: { stringValue: 'The Breaker' },
        author: { stringValue: 'Don Gold' },
    },
    name: 'projects/myproj/databases/(default)/documents/books/38',
    updateTime: '2023-02-22T07:17:31.413935Z'
}
```

Is there an api method to get the `fields` property as "normal" json, ie without the type definitions?

**CLARIFICATION ----------**

With "normal" json I meant no type info, but getting the `fields` data on name/value format, in the example above it would be `{ title: 'The Breaker', author: 'Don Gold' }`.

I first expected the `data()` method used in the [Firestore Events documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#event_triggers) to work, but it doesn't: In that library the following is possible:

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  // Get an object representing the document
  // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
  const newValue = snap.data();
  ...
```

and I am looking for an equivalent to that data method.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal" JSON? Please share what you exactly expect compare to what you get when logging the `data` object. Also, `console.log(data.fields);` doesn't return what you are looking for?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that you want to be able to have `console.log(data.fields)` and it spit out `{ title: 'The Breaker', author: 'Don Gold' }`? So you want to convert the protobuf formatted data into basic JavaScript types?

Comment: Yes, sorry for being unclear, it is as @samthecodingman says. I will update the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can spend time mucking around with [`protobufjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs) to get it to work, or you can hack a solution together such as this one:

**Note**: This will not work for all data types supported that are encoded for use with `protobuf`, I have implemented only a handful of the [possible types](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/Value) below.

Assuming `event.value` looks like:

```json
{
    "createTime": "2023-02-22T07:17:31.413935Z",
    "fields": {
        "title": { "stringValue": "The Breaker" },
        "author": { "stringValue": "Don Gold" },
    },
    "name": "projects/myproj/databases/(default)/documents/books/38",
    "updateTime": "2023-02-22T07:17:31.413935Z"
}
```

```js
const lazyDecodeProtobuf = (rawObj) => {
  if ("fields" in rawObj) { // handles MapValues
    let fieldName, decoded = {}, fieldsObj = rawObj.fields;
    for (fieldName in fieldsObj) {
      decoded[fieldName] = lazyDecodeProtobuf(fieldsObj[fieldName])
    }
    return decoded;
  } else if ("values" in rawObj) { // handles ArrayValues
    return rawObj.values.map(lazyDecodeProtobuf);
  }

  let fieldName, protobufType, rawValue;
  for (protobufType in rawObj) {
    rawValue = rawObj[protobufType];
    switch (protobufType) { // TODO: handle special types as needed
      case "timestampValue": // Example: converts timestamp objects to JS Dates
        return new Date(rawValue.seconds * 1e3 + rawValue.nanos / 1e6);
      case "integerValue":
        return Number(rawValue); // use with care
      default: // use value as-is (works for strings, booleans, nulls)
        return rawValue;
    }
  }
}

const data = lazyDecodeProtobuf(event.value);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
// logs:
// {
//  "title": "The Breaker",
//  "author": "Don Gold"
// }
```

See the [list of possible values](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/Value) for the different types you can expect to encounter for Firestore (such as [Timestamp](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#timestamp) and [ArrayValue](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/ArrayValue). There's a [broader set of types](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/) supported by protobuf, but not all of them are supported by Cloud Firestore Documents.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'll probably end up using something along those lines, after all I know how my data looks so no need to cover all possible cases. I was just expecting this to be built in behavior and just me not finding the right method, getting lost in the Google Cloud documentation as always :-)